# Using mutate() but keep getting the unexpected '=' error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm new to the mutate() function and I keep getting this message when trying to recode some of my values:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"table %>% mutate(SEX_R = recode(SEX, 
  1 ="
```

I use the same syntax recommended by countless of website, but it's not working.
Here's the code:

```
table %>% mutate(SEX_R = recode(SEX, 
  1 = "Male",
  2 = "Female"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the values in quotation marks in the recode() function like this:

```
table %>% mutate(SEX_R = recode(SEX, 
  "1" = "Male",
  "2" = "Female"))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked and I just learned that I also had to convert 1 and 2 to characters.

Answer (score 1):

`recode()` is superseded by `case_match()` in dplyr 1.1.0.

```
table %>% mutate(SEX_R = case_match(SEX,
  1 ~ "Male",
  2 ~ "Female"))
```